# Can we save a class in a variable a target an element with that variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="modern">
   <button>Ex 1</button>
  <li>
  <li class="classic">
   <button>Ex 2</button>
  </li>
<ul>

<path class="modern"></path>
<path class="classic"></path>
```

**CSS**

```
path {
  display: none;
}
```

When I click on a button, the path with the same class as the clicked parent button, should `fadeIn();`

The following is the **jQuery** I am trying

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var periodClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    if($("path").hasClass(periodClass)) {
        $("path.periodClass").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("path.periodClass").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to iterate all the `path`s. Use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: why down vote i do not know

Comment: It's not me... Sorry for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate it down, you can't access variables inside of JS like you can in PHP:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  let periodClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");

  // Hide others:
  $('path').not('.'+periodClass).fadeOut();
  $('path.'+periodClass).fadeIn();
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/o7r73o7w/1/)

Comment: `$('path')` will return a collection but not a single element so `hasClass` will not work very well..